Upgrading a project using older libraries
I'm really interested in this project and I'm trying to learn app development and ML through it, but I'm unable to make it work due to it being quite old and I'm getting a lot of errors regarding older libraries and whatnot. I'm getting these errors as shown in this image here.
Please help me fix this or guide me! Thanks a lot <3 Sorry if it's a dumb question but I'm sort of a beginner and this project really appeals to me.
I've tried updating the library versions of whatever is mentioned but something new keeps popping up.

The way to solve this (quite obviously, I might say) is to actually update the libraries to the newest versions. When "something new keeps popping up" then also fix that. When you have done that and there is still something off then please [edit] the question to specifically describe the issue you have. Also, the screenshot mostly shows warnings, not errors. The only "errors" are the ones warning you that Google's app store won't accept the app when using such old versions. But as you stated you only use the app to "learn app development" that's not a problem, the app will still work.

Only the first two are errors, the rest are warnings, and they even come with reasons and suggestions on fixing it.
